# Ehcache: Accessing same data and index file using two cache manager

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I start a process, which creates a cache manager and it access data and index file in certain location, now I start a different process and want to access same data and index files using cache manager of this process, Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

No, EhCache won't let you do this. If a `CacheManager` detects a given location is already in use (it uses lock files), it'll force itself to use a different location.

If you need to have multiple processes sharing cache data, then have a look at the sections of the [EhCache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/index.html) that talk about replicated caching.